How do I make tsc not emit test files (but still type check)?
How do I make test files are not emitted on compile, but still get type checked? Test files are those specified by the glob **/*\.test\.ts.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noEmit

you can have a
tsconfig.build.json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": [
      "**/*.test.ts"
    ]
}

and append -p tsconfig.build.json to your tsc command

Nope, this will also omit those from type checks
